# Finding the number of multiples in an interval [1, x] using the floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Show that for every real number $x \geq 1$, the number of multiples of $m$ in the interval $[1,x]$ is $\left \lfloor \frac{x}{m} \right \rfloor$.

I am taking an elementary number theory course and I am new to proofs, but this one is confusing me.

My attempt:
Let $x \geq 1$. 
$x = n - \varepsilon$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon\ \in [0,1)$.
Now by the Division Algorithm:
$n = m y + r$; for some positive integer $y$ and $0 \leq r < m$.
Then $x = n - \varepsilon = my + r - \varepsilon$
Dividing by $m$:
$\frac{x}{m} = y - \frac{\varepsilon - r}{m}$

This is where I get stuck. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I know that this is not how you are doing the proof, but this is how I would do it:

1. I would write $x=n+\epsilon$ so $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$.
2. Then, try to show that $\lfloor{\frac x m}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac n m\rfloor$ and then show that there are no integers in $(n, x]$ and thus we don't need to look for divisors there.
3. Thus, you just need to show that the number of multiples in $[1, n]$ is $\lfloor{\frac n m}\rfloor$ which you can do by induction on $n$. For this induction, the base case is $1$ and there are two cases for proving $P(n-1) \implies P(n)$: $n$ is not a multiple of $m$ and $n$ is a multiple of $m$. In the former case, $\lfloor{\frac n m}\rfloor=\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{m}}\rfloor$ and in the latter case, $\lfloor{\frac n m}\rfloor=\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{m}}\rfloor+1$.

With steps 1 and 2, I shifted the focus on the proof from $x$, a real number, to $n$, an integer, which is a lot easier to work with because we can use regular induction.